# Spectrum router (wireless) How do I get in to change settings?

Tags: networking

The router is a Sagemcom SAC2V2S and I am trying to use my Echo to run the lights with its modules, but the modules refuse the connection (they operate on 2.4GHz; router has both 2.4GHz and 5GHz wireless).

How can I get in and turn off the 5GHz wireless?

Comment: You appear to be having trouble with your capslock - see https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation should tell you. 192.168.1.1 is a common access method.

Here is the setup guide for this router.

[Router Setup](https://www.router-reset.com/howto-login-Sagemcom-router-and-access-settings)

> Open your browser and type the router's IP address into the address
> field. The most common IP for Sagemcom routers is: 192.168.1.1  If
> that IP address doesn't work, you can search the default Sagemcom IP
> address list for your specific model. (Source:
> https://www.router-reset.com/howto-login-Sagemcom-router-and-access-settings)

Common usernames and passwords are here

[User names and passwords](https://www.router-reset.com/default-password-ip-list/Sagemcom)